# Unique Index Fail

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-index

I created a unique index for employee IDs to an existing table.  I did a test and entered an employee ID already saved in the database, and the database still saved it.  When I do a search on that ID it lists both records.

Test the index by inserting a record with a duplicate employee ID

```
CREATE INDEX empid_index ON staff (empId)
```

Expected an error message of a duplicated ID, but no error came up, the record was still saved.

Comment: You haven´t created a unique index with that sentence. To do so you need to do **CREATE UNIQUE INDEX empid_index ON staff (empId)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: Why isn't that the `PRIMARY KEY`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create unique indexes: add **unique constraints** to the table instead. For example:

```
create table staff (
  ...
  constraint unique_empid unique (empid),
  ...
);
```

Even though unique indexes will prevent you from inserting duplicate rows with that value, you will be missing other features of the constraint, such as exporting foreign keys, that you may need later on.